# i want to create such type of array in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift3, nsdictionary

i want to create such type of dictionary within array in swift 3, I did it but instead of curly brackets it comes square bracket.i want dictionary in curly brackets.

[ { "interest_id":1 } ,  {"interest_id":2},  {"interest_id":3}]

Comment: What you want is JSON representation of Dictionaries and Array. That's different.

Comment: yes i want the same json representation.

Comment: Look for `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
let dictArray = [ [ "interest_id":1 ] , ["interest_id":2], ["interest_id":3]]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let json = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        print("json data: ", json )
    }
    catch {
        print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```